# jQuery bug when using bounce effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have problem with jQuery bounce effect. Every thing works good when there is no bounce - with bounce, when You move very fast many times on button - in sometime, box just doesn't hide. What is wrong in this jsfiddle?

My jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d6mSA/170/

My JS:

```
$('.flex_section').delegate('a','mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
var a = $(this).attr('id');

if (e.type == 'mouseenter'){

    clearTimeout(t_on)

    if (a == 'abc'){
    clearTimeout(t_off)     
    t_on = setTimeout(function() { popup_show(a,t_on); }, 10);
    }
} else {

    t_off = setTimeout(function() { popup_remove(a,t_off); }, 1000);
}
)}

function popup_show(type,string){
if (type == 'abc'){

    $('#pc_' + type).css('display','block');
    $('#pc_' + type).effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:20},1000);
}
clearTimeout(string);
}
function popup_remove(type,string){
    $('#pc_' + type).css('display','none');
    clearTimeout(string)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
function popup(){
    $('.flex_top a').hover(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('id');
        var offset = $('#' + type).offset();
        $('#id_' + type).css('display','block')
        .offset({left:offset.left + 100, top:offset.top + 380})
        .effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:20},1000);
    },function(){
       var type = $(this).attr('id');
       $('#id_' + type).fadeOut();
    }
  );
}
```

And dont call many times the same object search `$('#id_' + type)`

Comment: hm, it works better but now i have problem with many box when i move many times very fast on button. But it's some progress :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$('#pc_' + type).stop().effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:20},1000);
```

Comment: when i add stop() or .finish(), box sometimes lost possition